# How to get back text ellipsis in pandas jupyter lab

Tags: python, css, pandas, jupyter-lab, pandas-styles

I am displaying a pandas dataframe in jupyter lab. Some cells have very long text, and if I put:
`df.style` it will make the rows very high. Setting: `df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector="tr",props=[('text-overflow', 'ellipsis'),('overflow', 'hidden'), ('height', '20px')])])` has no effect unfortunately.

I confirmed the setting are being used by setting the height to a high value, it works and changes the row height. Only there seems to be a minimum value for the height somehow, determined by the amount of text in a cell.

Setting it on 'td' and adding `'white-space:nowrap'` at least makes the rows all the same height, but now the columns get really wide:

`df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector="td",props=[('text-overflow', 'ellipsis'),('overflow', 'hidden'), ('white-space','nowrap'), ('height', '20px')])])`

Comment: seems one of my td values had some \n and $ signs which were making trouble

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue. Tried to use [pandas styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) to get html/css code to be rendered nicely in a [flask app](https://flask.palletsprojects.com) and the text of a column was overflowing. My solution was to include the "text-overflow: ellipsis" class in html and the accompanying JS code (see below).

in something_something**.html** (the "{{ }}" is [Jinja templating](http://jinja.pocoo.org/))

```
<div id="table_id" class="table table-striped hover text-overflow: ellipsis"> {{ pd_DataFrame_style_rendered | safe }} </div>
```

in something_something**.css**

```
.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}
```

Hope this helps.